# Sqlalchemy Database Query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Please, I need help on how to query for this type of data in sqlalchemy. I have a model design in this format.

```
class Parent(db.model):
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    friends = db.Column(db.String)
    account_status = db.Column(db.String, default='Inactive')
```

so, i want to query for:

```
my_friends = Parent.query.filter_by(friends=current_user.name).all()
```

which actually give me a list of users who have me has their friends, but I also want to only query for user who have me and has their friends but who's account status are 'Active' and count them.

Thanks, all contribution are welcome and accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED 
`filter()` can take more than one condition.

```py
my_friends = Parent.query.filter((Parent.friends==current_user.name) & 
(Parent.account_status=="Active")).all()
```

This code returns a list. If you want to count them, use `len(my_friends)`.

Comment: this throw an error of: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'friends' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

@Muhteva thanks for trying to help, your answer give me the solution to my problem.
when i tried to query it the same way you did it return a Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> NameError: 
name 'friends' is not defined
```

but when i study your code well i come up with this which work for me:
instead of querying the db like this:

```
my_friends = Parent.query.filter((friends==current_user.name) & 
(account_status=="Active")).all()
```

i queried it this way including the Model class name to the column name:

```
my_friends = Parent.query.filter((Parent.friends==current_user.name) & 
(Parent.account_status=="Active")).all()
```

which work for me. All Thanks to @Muhteva for giving me a clue on how to achieve this.

Comment: please accept the answer if it helped you solve the problem

Comment: Glad to be helpful

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 have done just that. and thanks once again Muhteva. you saved my life from over thinking. thank you alot.